# Derive the dual function $g(\lambda, \nu)$ for the least-norm problem

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, normed-spaces, convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to find the dual function $g(\lambda, \nu)$  to this problem

$$\min\limits_{Ax = b} \|x\|$$

**Step 1. Form the Lagrangian**

$$L(x, \lambda, \nu) = \|x\| + \nu^T(Ax-b) = \|x\| + \nu^TAx - \nu^Tb$$

**Step 2. Take the inf over all $x$ to get $g(\lambda, \nu)$**

$g(\lambda, \nu)$  = $\inf\limits_x (\|x\| + \nu^TAx - \nu^Tb)$

Then by property of $\inf$, we have:

$\inf\limits_x (\|x\| + \nu^TAx - \nu^Tb) = \inf\limits_x \|x\| +  \inf\limits_x \nu^TAx -  \inf\limits_x \nu^Tb$

Notice:

- $-  \inf\limits_x \nu^Tb =  -\nu^Tb$, not much to do here
- $ \inf\limits_x \nu^TAx =  \inf\limits_x (A^T\nu)^Tx$ looks like a dual norm i.e. $\|A^T\nu\|_{*} = \inf\limits_x\{ (A^T\nu)^Tx | \|x\|\leq 1\}$, but here we have a constraint $\|x\|\leq 1$

Then we have

$g(\lambda, \nu)$  = $\inf\limits_x (\|x\| + \nu^TAx - \nu^Tb) = \inf\limits_x \|x\| + \|A^T\nu\|_{*} - \nu^Tb$, $\|x\| \leq 1$

Does anyone know how to deal with the $\|x\| \leq 1$ constraint and proceed from above?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do... you have a valid dual function before the dual norm rewrite. What's the goal here?

Comment: $\lambda$ seems to be a "ghost" variable. Remove it from your equations.

Comment: It's not valid to distribute the $\text {inf} $ like that.

Comment: Yes, this is very invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your're almost there...

Recall the definition of [*convex conjugates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate). Recall that the convex conjugate of a norm $\|.\|$ is the indicator function of the unit ball of the dual norm $\|.\|_*$. Now,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
g(\nu) &:= \underset{x}{\inf }L(x,\nu) = \underset{x}{\inf }\|x\| + \nu^T Ax - \nu^T b = \nu^Tb -\underset{x}{\sup }x^T(-A^T\nu) - \|x\|\\
&= \nu^Tb -\|.\|^*(-A^T\nu) =  \begin{cases}\nu^Tb, &\mbox{ if }\|A^T\nu\|_* \le 1,\\-\infty, &\mbox{ else.}\end{cases}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Thus the dual problem is:
\begin{equation}
\text{Maximize } \nu^Tb\text{ subject to }\|A^T\nu\|_* \le 1.
\end{equation}

**Example:**
For example, if $\|.\|$ is the $\ell_1$-norm, then your original problem is the well-known *Basis Pursuit problem*, and the dual we've obtained is a linear program (you're maximizing a linear function on a polytope).

**Notes:** Using the [Fenchel-Rockafellar duality Theorem](https://people.ok.ubc.ca/bauschke/Research/68.pdf), you can obtain the sought-for dual formulation in exactly one line!

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer! I have two questions, 1. Is there a simple way to show that the convex conjugate of $\| \cdot \|$ is the indicator function on the unit ball of dual norm $\| \cdot \|_{*}$. I don't think I have encountered this claim in my study. How did you go from $\nu^Tb - \sup\limits_x (x^T(-A^T\nu) - \|x\|)$ to $v^Tb - \|\cdot\|^*(-A^T\nu)$? Specifically what is a $\|\cdot\|^*$? Lastly, how did the $\|A^Tv\|_{*} \leq 1$ come about? --- (I don't think I know much about convex conjugates but I will look into it)

Comment: $f^*$ denotes the convex conjugate of $f$. Thus $\|.\|^*$ denotes the convex conjugate of the norm $\|.\|$. About convex conjugates of norms, see my answer to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1477721/168758.  To get a big picture of all this, please read on convex conjugates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate. I think you have the necessary background to understand these things.

Comment: Hey Dohmatob I am revisiting this problem and I am convinced that there must be a easier method. Pg 5 https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures/duality.pdf shows an elegant relationship between the primal and the dual problem via the dual norm. Do you know if there is a simpler way to see why given a primal function under the primal norm, the dual problem is constrained by the dual norm?

Comment: This is because the dual norm is defined as the support function of the unit ball of the primal norm. Any other 'reason' will invariable be a restatement of the this fact, using a possibly different wording :)

Comment: @dohmatob, Great Answer. +1. It would be great if you showed the explicit solution for $ {L}_{2} $ Norm.