# why dual of $l_1$ norm is $l_\infty$ and vice versa

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

This might be a very dumb question but I am having a hard time to understand why dual of $l_1$ norm is $l_\infty$ and vice versa. The dual of a norm is denoted $\lVert\cdot\rVert_*$, defined as
$$
\lVert z\rVert_*=\sup\left\{z^Tx\mid\: \lVert x\rVert\leq1\right\}
$$
and $l_1$ norm is,
$$
\lVert x\rVert_1 = \sum(|x_i|)
$$
and $l_\infty$ norm is,
$$
\lVert x\rVert_\infty = \max(|x_1|,...,|x_n|)
$$
I am very confused on dual norm. Any explanation would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Well, have you seen a proof that the sual of a dual norm is the original norm?

Comment: You get this via a rather direct computation, playing with basic notions like indicator function, etc. See my answer to a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1477721/168758.

Comment: Are you working with these norms on $\,mathbb R^n$? Since for sequences spaces $\ell_\infty^*\ne\ell_1$.