# Proximal operator of the addition of a quadractic term and Lasso penalty

Tags: regularization, proximal-operators

I am trying to derive the proximal operator $\operatorname{prox}_{\lambda}f(v), v \in \mathbb R^n$ of the addition between a quadratic term and a lasso penalty
$f(x) = \lVert b - Ax \rVert_2^2 + \tau \|x\|_1.$

This is different from the question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961888/the-proximal-operator-of-the-l-1-norm-function).

The soft-thresholding operator is the proximal of the lasso regularizer $\|x\|_1$. I also know how to compute the proximal of the squared error loss $\lVert b - Ax \rVert_2^2$ as it is a quadratic function of $x.$

I may use the pre-composition property (Section 2.2, Proximal Algorithms, Parikh & Boyd) for deriving the proximity operator of $f$, but I am unsure how to define it.

[In the same book, they propose this derivation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hsfo.png)

> If $f(x) = \phi(x) + (\rho/2)\lvert x - a \rvert_2^2$, then
> $$\boldsymbol{\operatorname{prox}}_{\lambda f}(\nu) = \boldsymbol{\operatorname{prox}}_{\tilde \lambda \phi} \left( (\tilde \lambda / \lambda ) \nu + (\rho \tilde \lambda) a \right).$$

The function $\phi$ can be taken as Lasso. However, in my case $x$ is multiplied by a matrix $A.$

Comment: Has been asked here before.

Comment: E.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961888/the-proximal-operator-of-the-l-1-norm-function).

Comment: @Ramanujan It's not the same question. I'm interested in the proximal of the sum between the l1-norm and a quadratic term.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is explicitly written out anywhere. Under some conditions on $A$, you can often determine $\textrm{prox}_{f\circ A}$ in terms of $\textrm{prox}_f$, $A$, and $A^\top$ (The book by Bauschke & Combettes, vol. 2 has these sort of identities). However, since a linear operator only appears in *one* of the terms, these results don't immediately apply. So you may need to derive this result yourself, but those proofs should provide candidates for potential assumptions on $A$. Also see http://proximity-operator.net/multivariatefunctions.html for a good reference

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Zim