# what is fenchel transformation of $f(x) = |x|$?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I gathered different handouts from the internet and tried to figure out what fenchel transformation was, but I stumbled on two different results of fenchel transformation of $f(x) = |x|$:

First results is:

[image]

Second result is:

[image]

I believe the first one is correct but can anyone confirm this for me? In addition, should there be vertical lines at $p=-1$ and $p=1$?

Comment: It's the indicator function (in the sense of convex analysis) of the compact interval [-1, 1]. This is a very very special case of a more general result https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1477721.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is written explicitly in the wikipedia page about [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate). In your case, one has
$$
f^\star(x^*) = \sup_\limits{x\in \mathbb{R}}\{x^* x - |x|\}
=\left\{{0\text{ if } |x^*|\le 1\atop +\infty\text{ if }|x^*|\gt  1}\right.
$$

Your first picture tries to represent the subderivative, a related concept.

**Edit**: the biconjugate is here

$$
f^{\star\star}(x) = \sup_\limits{x^*\in\mathbb{R}}(x^* x - f^\star(x^*))
= \sup_\limits{x^*\in[-1, 1]}(x^* x) = |x| = f(x)
$$

This is the expected result because $f$ is convex.

Comment: Okay, so are you saying that the first one is correct? but shouldn’t the subdifferential of the conjugate be x as shown in the second picture? I’m having trouble transforming the conjugate back to the original.

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: I’m sorry but what exactly is the difference between the two? One is a subderivative(do you mean subdifferential?) and the other isn’t? Are they both correct but mean different stuff?

Comment: The [subderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) (or subdifferential) is related to the [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate) (or Legendre-Fenchel transformation), but it is a different object.